# get the branch name from a svn pre-commit request using c#

Tags: c#, svn

We already have a pre-commit.exe hook written in c# that either allows all commits or blocks all. I am trying to set it up to where it only blocks the svn branches that I specify but for that I need to know how to get the branch that the pre-commit is going to.

Is the only way to do this is to use svnlook and see the files that it is changing?  If so, how do I get the branch from that? (with c# code)

Any thoughts?

Any help is very much appreciated!